# how to grab html of clicked link and copy to specific input field

Tags: html, input, hyperlink, copy, field

Hi guys I want to grab the html value of a link which is clicked and copy the value to a specific input field with .this it should work someone a quick advice or piece of code? Would be great to get quick help.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
<input id="hrefvalue" type="text" />
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');        
        $("#hrefvalue").val(href);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyrhg803/1/)

Comment: works great man but is there a possibility to grab also the html value and title value and another data attribute value from link and insert into three other seperated input fields?